ssh -- client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
I came across client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe problem when I ssh from a Ubuntu server to another Ubuntu server. The connection will automatically close out after 15 mins idle time. I think it is a good security feature to automatically time-out an idle ssh session. However, I would like to control "15 mins" to other suitable interval, such as "60 mins".
There are lots of posts on using

ClientAliveInterval option in sshd_config on ssh server side; or
ServerAliveInterval option in ssh_config on client side

But both these options are to help ssh to detect a failed communication channel and successfully close out a "broken" ssh session; rather than to control the session time-out interval due to idle.
Here is my solution to "control" a ssh session's idle time and disconnect the ssh session  if it has been idle longer than the desired threshold; 3600 seconds

On ssh server side sshd_config; enable ClientAliveInterval option with an interval less than 900 second. This will keep ssh session always live with a healthy communication channel and solve client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe problem. Restart sshd.service using sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
on ssh server side /etc/profile file; at the end of the file, add

TMOUT=3600 # disconnect the shell after being idle for 1 hour
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT

Now any new ssh connection to the server will be automatically terminated if it has been idle for more than 1 hour with the following message on server side
timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
